# Undefined method strict in cucumber

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, capybara

When using Guerkin and cucumber, I get an `undefined method strict?'` error.

### Spec

```
my feature
#language: pt
# utf-8

@regression_cad
Funcionalidade: Validar as funções de criação de Conta

Contexto: 
Dado que o usuário esteja na Home de Cadastro de Conta

@conta_invalida
Esquema do Cenario: Fornecer dados inválidos na conta
Quando preencher os campos "<cnpj>" "<cpf>" "<celular>" "<email_corp>" "<fat_anual>" "<senha>" e "<confirma_senha>"
Então posso ver a mensagem "<alerta>" 

  Exemplos:
  | cnpj |  cpf | celular | email_corp | fat_anual | senha | confirma_senha | alerta  |
  | 065  |  045 | 11      | sivin      |350        | Teste | teste          |   fafavo|

My code:
Dado('que o usuário esteja na Home de Cadastro de Conta') do                                                                                                     
    screen_cadastro.load
    page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
    page.execute_script "window.scrollBy(0,700)"                                                                                   
  end                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                   
  Quando('preencher os campos {string} {string} {string} {string} {string} {string} e {string}') do | 
 ncnpj, ncpf, ncelular, nemail_corp, nfat_anual, n_senha, nconfirma_senha| 
    screen_cadastro.cnpj.set(ncnpj).send_keys(:tab)
    screen_cadastro.cpf.set(ncpf).send_keys(:tab)                                                                                  
  end                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                   
  Então('posso ver a mensagem {string}') do |msg_alert|                                                                                                               
    pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions                                                                                    
  end    


cucumber -t @onta_invalida

My error: 
  @conta_invalida
  Esquema do Cenario: Fornecer dados inválidos na conta                                                                 # features/smoke_test/conta.feature:11
    Quando preencher os campos "<cnpj>" "<cpf>" "<celular>" "<email_corp>" "<fat_anual>" "<senha>" e "<confirma_senha>" # features/smoke_test/conta.feature:12
    Então posso ver a mensagem "<alerta>"                                                                               # features/smoke_test/conta.feature:13

    Exemplos:
      | cnpj |  cpf | celular | email_corp | fat_anual | senha | confirma_senha | alerta  |
```

### Result

```
----------------------------------------------
Scenario: Fornecer dados inválidos na conta
The results is: P
----------------------------------------------

undefined method `strict?' for :passed:Symbol (NoMethodError)
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/result.rb:197:in `ok?'
C:/Temp/QFLASH/AUT_FRONT/features/support/hooks.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in `block in broadcast'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in `each'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in `broadcast'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:40:in `method_missing'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/runner.rb:22:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-5.2.0/lib/cucumber/filters/prepare_world.rb:11:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:57:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-5.2.0/lib/cucumber/filters/retry.rb:18:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-5.2.0/lib/cucumber/filters/quit.rb:11:in `test_case'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb:28:in `describe_to'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-5.2.0/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:21:in `block in done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-5.2.0/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:20:in `map'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-5.2.0/lib/cucumber/filters/broadcast_test_run_started_event.rb:20:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/locations_filter.rb:20:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/filter.rb:62:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/test/filters/tag_filter.rb:18:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/compiler.rb:31:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core/gherkin/parser.rb:46:in `done'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:35:in `parse'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-core-8.0.1/lib/cucumber/core.rb:24:in `compile'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-5.2.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:79:in `run!'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-5.2.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:29:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-5.2.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What do your dependencies look like? Looks like you have two different versions of Cucumber in your project.

Comment: oh Sorry, i gonna see that!!!